# Can a callout be used in Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I currently have a custom list in SharePoint online and I need to add some kind of tooltip that displays certain information. I've found out about callouts but i'm not sure if I can use those in Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Formatting is your friend here. Check out this example

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/text-startswith-callingcodes

[image]

You can basically set the 'title' attribute to anything you want to get the Tooltip on your custom field